# Why is NSPredicate evaluateWithObject nil when searching for string within NSMutableArray loaded from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist, nspredicate

I am trying to check within a plist if I had previously saved the value (song) before. 
Basically why is this:

```
    if ([condition evaluateWithObject:favoritesArray] == YES) {
        return;
    }
```

being evaluated to nil while this:

```
if ([[favoritesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:condition] count] != 0) {
        return;
}
```

works perfectly fine with the exact same condition.

Sample of plist:

```
(
        {
        artist = Yuna;
        image = "";
        isFavorite = 1;
        song = "I Wanna Go (BELARBI REMIX)";
        thumbnail = "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/94177627.png";
    }
)
```

printed condition:

```
song = "I Wanna Go (BELARBI REMIX)"
```

Note: changing condition to "song LIKE %@" gives me an "Can't do regex matching on object" error. "song.song" is a NSString.

Here is the full code below:

```
- (void) saveFavorite: (Songs*)song
{
    NSMutableArray *favoritesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[MBCUtils dataFilePathWithFile:@"favorites.plist"]];
    NSPredicate *condition = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"song == %@" argumentArray:@[song.song]];
    if (favoritesArray == nil) {
        favoritesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    } else {
        //favorite is already in list;
        NSLog(@"filtered favs: %@", [favoritesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:condition]);
        if ([[favoritesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:condition] count] != 0) {
            return;
        }
        // why this isn't working is beyond me;
        if ([condition evaluateWithObject:favoritesArray] == YES) {
            return;
        }
    }
    [favoritesArray addObject:[song toDictionary]];
    [favoritesArray writeToFile:[MBCUtils dataFilePathWithFile:@"favorites.plist"] atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[favoritesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:condition]
```

applies the predicate to *each element* in the array and returns an array with
the matching elements.

```
[condition evaluateWithObject:favoritesArray]
```

applies the predicate to the entire array, and that returns `NO`, because the array
has no "song" attribute. But if you modify the predicate to

```
NSPredicate *condition = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY song == %@" argumentArray:@[song.song]];
// Or simply:
NSPredicate *condition = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY song == %@", song.song];
```

then

```
[condition evaluateWithObject:favoritesArray]
```

should give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

EvaluateWithObject: does't work because "song" is not an property (or key) of favoritesArray. If you passed the single dictionary that you show in your post to evaluateWithObject:, it would work since "song" is a key of that dictionary. The method, filteredArrayUsingPredicate: takes each member of the array (a dictionary in your case), and applies the predicate to it.